# fade effect keeps repeating as many times as I hover

Tags: jquery, html, animation, fade, repeat

I am using fade effect to hide & show two divs as I hover over them. The only problem is that Animation keeps repeating as many times as I hover over it even though it's an accidental & it's kind of annoying.

I use .stop(true, false) method for animate.

Like this:

```
$('.fallInspiration').hover(
   function(){
      $(this).stop(true, false).animate({color: '#D55E8E'}, 300);
},
```

But I don't know how to go about fixing the problem when using fade effect.

Here's the code I am using:

```
$('.thisWeekWrap').hover(
    function()
    {
        $('.thisWeek').fadeOut(400);
        $('.thisWeekHover').fadeIn(400);
    },
    function()
    {
        $('.thisWeek').fadeIn(400);
        $('.thisWeekHover').fadeOut(400);
    }
);
```

Help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: can you make a reproduceable version on jsFiddle.net?

Comment: what's the relevance of the first code block?  Surely you need some `.stop()` calls in the second code block?

Answer (score 7):

You answered your own question: call `.stop()` before doing the effects:

```
$('.thisWeek').stop().fadeOut( 400 )
```

if this causes issues (it may, sometimes jQuery "saves" the stopped values), try:

```
$('.thisWeek').stop().animate({ opacity : 0 }, 400);
```

Comment: this worked well for my use case! this should be accepted. if i move my mouse off the div, it stops the fadein (and fades it out). thank you!